# Best statistical test to determine how well measurements using two different methods correspond

Tags: statistics

I am conducting a study in which essentially I am measuring a set of lengths using two different methods. After all of the data is collected, I'd like to test how close the measurements of each method are for corresponding lengths. Since they are measuring the same lengths, ideally if the measurements produced by the two methods are plotted against each other, they should form the line y=x. Beyond trying this and checking the best-fit slope and correlation coefficient, is there a way to more rigorously test how well the two methods coincide in their measurements, and find the approximate error? Perhaps find the average distance of points from the line y=x?

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction.** A paired t-test is a correct procedure if measurements are approximately
normal. The test statistic is $T = \frac{\bar D}{S_D/\sqrt{n}},$ where
$\bar D$ is the mean of the paired differences and $S_D$ is their standard
deviation. Under the null hypothesis that the population mean difference is 0,
you have $T \sim T(n-1),$ Student's t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of
freedom, where $n$ is the number of pairs.

If the measurements are obviously far from normal, then you might use 
a *Wilcoxon Signed Rank* test. (You can look for details in an elementary
statistics text or on Wikipedia.)

Your idea of plotting the data and comparing the plot with the 45-degree line
is a good one. It can also give rise to a test, called a *Sign Test,* which
uses the binomial distribution. (The idea is that if the null hypothesis
is true, then there will be about the same number of points on both sides of
that line.

**Simulated data.** Below are $n = 25$ simulated pairs of (normally distributed) measurements, which I use to illustrate these three tests. I am using R statistical software, but
almost any statistical package will do the same tests.

Data are rounded to 2 places; numbers in brackets are indexes of first number in each row of output.

```
round(x1, 2)
 [1]  96.78  89.27 134.14 112.47  46.71 128.28 106.51  77.36 123.17
[10] 119.97 100.46  99.92  99.18 106.09 112.39  97.74 114.35 117.12
[19]  86.45  89.23  84.29  91.87  77.75  95.94 114.66
round(x2, 2)
 [1]  95.35  86.49 131.81 115.16  46.04 127.12 106.53  76.88 123.52
[10] 115.36  99.14  99.52 100.49 102.12 113.01 100.40 113.64 119.42
[19]  84.58  91.92  86.61  93.05  76.11  99.54 116.27
round(d,2)
 [1] -1.43 -2.78 -2.33  2.69 -0.68 -1.16  0.01 -0.48  0.36 -4.61
[11] -1.32 -0.40  1.31 -3.97  0.62  2.66 -0.71  2.30 -1.87  2.69
[21]  2.33  1.18 -1.64  3.60  1.61
```

Here is a histogram of the differences. They seem centered around 0.
The histogram hardly looks normal, but it doesn't look non-normal either.
(It would take a much larger
sample size before we would expect to see an 'obviously normal shaped' histogram.)

[image]

**Paired t test**

```
t.test(x1, x2, pair=T)

        Paired t-test

data:  x1 and x2 
t = 0.1838, df = 24, p-value = 0.8557
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
             0.08018935
```

We cannot reject the null hypothesis that the two measurements give
the same values on average. The printout shows this by giving a P-value.
Testing at the 5% level of significance, one would not reject the null
hypothesis if the P-value exceeds 5%. Also, the values $\pm 2.064$ cut off
probability 2.5% from each tail of $T(24),$ so we would not reject the
null hypothesis if $|T| < 2.064$ (here we have $T = 0.1838$).

**Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test**

```
wilcox.test(x1, x2, pair=T)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  x1 and x2 
V = 169, p-value = 0.874
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

The conclusion here is the same as for the t test.

**Sign Test**

A plot of $X_2$ values against $X_1$ values, compared with a 45-degree line,
is shown below. (Some points almost fall on top of others, but there really are 25.)
The sample correlation is $r = 0.993,$ which reflects a strong linear
association between the two measurement methods. But this does not say
much about the mean difference being near 0. (A test to see if the y-intercept is consistent with 0 would, but I'm skipping that.)

[image]

There exactly 12 points for which the difference $D = X_2 - X_1$
is positive. If the two measurement methods are the same, then number of
pairs with positive differences would have a binomial distribution with
$n = 25$ and $\theta = .5$. The quantiles .025 and .975 of this distribution
are 8 and 17, respectively. We would not reject the null hypothesis if
the number of positive differences is between these two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you should use a Paired-T test.

For each length $L_i$ you measure by methods $a$ and $b$. For each measurement you subtract the $b$ measurement from the $a$ measurement.

So you looking for mean and standard deviation of the set of differences.

$L_{i,a} - L_{i,b}$